# Capitalize the text in textfield as user types it without using css text-transform?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already did solve this problem using css but i am not allowed to use css to capitalize the text as user types and then change the submitted data to uppercase before submitting? can anyone help me out with this using jquery/JS.

Comment: I would also make sure you capitalize it on the server side if it's important to have uppercase input. Remember, Javascript can always be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On keyup function the text box is capitalized but while editing the cursor position always forces to the end in most browser. It works like a charm

```
$(selector).on('keyup',function(){
   var start = this.selectionStart,
       end = this.selectionEnd;     
       this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
       this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

On `keyup event`. Just apply the method to convert to uppercase

```
this.value.toUpperCase();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZXxY/)**

But if you want the text to be in uppercase just before submitting the data. Then it is better you convert to upperCase once instead of binding it in `keyup event`..

```
// submit here
      var data = $('#input')[0].value.toUpperCase();
```

**[Change Event fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZXxY/1/)**

```
$("input").on('keyup', function(e) {
    if( [8,37,38].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1 ) {
        return;
    }
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

**[Another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZXxY/2/)**

You can use the keycode and check if either  backspace or arrow keys are pressed. Else capitalize or return it.

Comment: This solution does not let me go and change the text as it takes me back to the last letter in textbox

Comment: Then instead apply it on the change event , instead of `keyup`

Comment: it capitalizes as soon as textbox loses focus but what i am looking for is change it to uppercase as user types it

Comment: If a user where to try and type in the middle of the text, the first key would add a character in the middle and the rest would go at the end

Comment: @Sushanth-- i just triggered that problem too it forces the cursor to the end of textbox while editing it in between texts

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `keyup` event:

```
$("#idOfInput").keyup(function() {
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sqef8/

Answer (score 1):

You could trap a to z in keydown event and replace selected text with A-Z:

```
    function ucase(event, source) {
        var evt = event ? event : window.event;
        if (evt.keyCode >= 65 && evt.keyCode <= 90) {
            textboxReplaceSelect(source, String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode).toUpperCase());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function textboxReplaceSelect(oTextbox, sText) {
        var isOpera = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") > -1;
        var isIE = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > 1 && !isOpera;
        var isMoz = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mozilla/5.") == 0 && !isOpera;
        if (isIE) {
            var oRange = document.selection.createRange();
            oRange.text = sText;
            oRange.collapse(true);
            oRange.select();
        } else if (isMoz) {
            var iStart = oTextbox.selectionStart;
            oTextbox.value = oTextbox.value.substring(0, iStart) + sText + oTextbox.value.substring(oTextbox.selectionEnd, oTextbox.value.length);
            oTextbox.setSelectionRange(iStart + sText.length, iStart + sText.length);
        }

        oTextbox.focus();
    }
```

Example of how to call it:

```
    <input type="text" onkeydown="return ucase(event,this);" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YbD2N/4/

Comment: I realized that it was specific to IE, I made it so it would work in other browsers, however I cannot test since I don't have any other installed on my computer

Comment: only IE? that's a new one. you can use pocket opera if you are afraid of installing a real browser, but man, do yourself and us a favor...

Comment: Company mentality, I got to get passed it, I tested and made it work in IE, Firefox and Chrome